# Is it correct to write $\nabla\times(\nabla\times\textbf{E})$ as $\nabla\times(\nabla\times)\cdot\textbf{E}$?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, differential-operators

Is it correct to write $\nabla\times(\nabla\times\textbf{E})$ as $\nabla\times(\nabla\times)\cdot\textbf{E}$ ? 
 I read this kind of expression on a book, but I wonder if it is correct to write it like this.

[A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW3qQ.png)

[B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CGjr.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please put `$` before and after each [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) expression.

Comment: That is odd! I would have said the latter is incorrect, but then again, I'm not sure what the author means.

Comment: Re: @diligar   The two equations are in a text book which I was reading. The equation B is derived from the equation A. I'm ok with the equation A, but I'm uncertain if the equation B is correct or not.  (Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: @K.Artorias My guess is the intent is to make $[\nabla\times(\nabla\times)+\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon_0c^2}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\varepsilon]$ a single operator and apply it to $E$. Weird but similar to the [d'Alembertian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Yeah, I understand what you mean. If they wish to make it a single operator,  I think $[\mathbf{curl}\mathbf{curl}+\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon_0c^2}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\varepsilon \cdot ]$ may be a better format.